# Change design of Tabel View - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, row

I want to change the design of my Table View. I'm learning Objective C and never changed my design for now. What I want to do is to put a line under every row like on WhatsApp. What is the easiest way to do is? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: If you are running on simulator, ensure that you are running simulator in 100% scale(command + 1) mode otherwise you will see the separator line disappeared while scrolling.

Comment: It's already 100% scale :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add following lines in viewDidLoad.

```
[self.table setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
[self.table setSeparatorColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

Or

From storyboard click on  tableview and set separator as (Single line). You can change separator color and insets too. Below is image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Worked! But now I even have lines where I don't have a photo with text (http://prntscr.com/b0j0ef), can I delete these lines ? Post edited btw

Comment: Yes , add this in viewdidload . self.table.footerview = [[UIViiew alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

Comment: What should I place instead of the 'self.table', I don't know much so it would help me so much if you explain in detail :)

Comment: Make a iBOutlet of table view , That will provide you this .https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html or search for any better tutorial

Answer (score 2):

By default `tableView` have separator line. Just check your tableView properties. may be separator is set to none

1.Select separator to single line.

2.Give Value for separator leftInset.

***check below gif image***

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the gif, very helpfull :D

Answer (score 1):

Table view have its property "Separator" you can directly set from xib or storyboard

Comment: Thanks. I used 'single line' in the Separator property and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should increase your table view cell height and than set table view setSeparatorStyle and setSeparatorColor. At last you should set set Separator Inset.

Comment: I increased the Tableview height, but the problem is that the image increases also in size. http://prntscr.com/b0jwrn

Answer (score 1):

set the Tableview height,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 90;
}
```

if you create TableView in Storyboard set separator in shown below,
[image]

hope its helpful

Comment: I increased the Tableview height with your code, but the problem is that the image increases also in size. prntscr.com/b0jwrn

Comment: You will properly set the **constraints** its not increased the `UIImageView `height, you fixed the `UIImageView` height.

Answer (score 1):

basically all the option available  on story board 
From storyboard click on tableview and set separator as (Single line). You can change separator color 
or in viewdidload add

self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blackcolor()

you also can change color of seprator line

Comment: Thanks. I used 'single line' in the Separator property and it worked.